# What is the width: -moz-available equivalent in WebKit?

Tags: css, webkit

What is the `width: -moz-available` equivalent in WebKit?

Answer (score 15):

It's now supported in WebKit as `width:-webkit-fill-available`, defined in CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3 (http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-sizing-20120927/#width-height-keywords).

Contrary to Gecko, which bases its implementation `width:-moz-available` on CSS basic box model (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-box/#the-width-and-height-properties).

Note that both values are defined in different terms; they may function differently in edge cases.  Furthermore, in the editor's draft (11 October 2013) of CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3, `fill-available` is now specified as `fill`.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in Chrome:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this requires the element's `width` to be set to `100%`.

Comment: This answer actually solved my problem : using `border-box` with `width: 100%` makes the element fill the remaining space perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't work if the element has margins