# resize image in div with browser window

Tags: css

I have an image in a div in a div in a div. I would like to resize the image to fit in the div , keeping aspect ratio. it works in firefox, but i can't get it to work in webkit based browsers.

It works in Firefox if the width is set to `width: -moz-available;` Is there anything similar in Chrome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383923/css-moz-available-equivalent-in-webkit0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image to `max-width: 100%`. If you need high quality scaling in IE7 or lower, also add an `AlphaImageLoader` filter with `sizingMethod='scale'`.