# Putting -moz-available and -webkit-fill-available in one width property

Tags: css

I want to make the width of the footer browser-independent.

For Firefox, I want to use the value of `-moz-available`, and when a user uses Opera, then CSS should get the values from `-webkit-fill-available`.

How can I do this in CSS?

I tried to do something like this:

```css
width: -moz-available, -webkit-fill-available;
```

but this won't give the desired results.

Comment: Just define the two properties as separate width declarations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383923/css-moz-available-equivalent-in-webkit

Comment: I did this:

 width: -moz-available;
width: -webkit-fill-available;

The result was what it not needed to be.

Comment: `width: -moz-available; width: -webkit-fill-available;` The browser will ignore declarations it doesn't understand.

Comment: Thats odd... I tried it the second time and now it works. Hmmm i guess CSS likes to tease me sometimes.

Comment: The thing is that FF and Chrome will not respect vendor prefixes for values. Comments here and answer below assumes it works the same as with the attribute names, but it's not. Here browsers seem to ignore prefixes and just classically apply whatever is defined last.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

CSS will skip over style declarations it doesn't understand. Mozilla-based browsers will not understand `-webkit`-prefixed declarations, and WebKit-based browsers will not understand `-moz`-prefixed declarations.

Because of this, we can simply declare `width` twice:

```css
elem {
    width: 100%;
    width: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: fill-available;
}
```

The `width: 100%` declared at the start will be used by browsers which ignore both the `-moz` and `-webkit`-prefixed declarations or do not support `-moz-available` or `-webkit-fill-available`.

NB: `fill-available` (which is in the spec as `stretch`) is still experimental, and should not be used in production.

Comment: `fill-available` has changed to `stretch` based on recent spec changes.

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#width-height-keywords and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Formal_syntax

Comment: this works with my firefox only if I put `-webkit-` first. If I put `-moz-` first, the browser ignores both for some reason. I got a feeling that this would do the same thing in chrome..

Answer (score 4):

You should use `stretch` instead of `fill-available`.

Comment: is `stretch` valid? i see it ignored in the browser

Comment: Why? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67554810/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Yes, we now use "stretch" and autoprefixer processes it as `height: -webkit-fill-available; height: -moz-available; height: stretch;`

Comment: This does not answer the question and should be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, min-width did the trick:

```
min-width: -moz-available;
min-width: -webkit-fill-available;
min-width: fill-available;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question and should be deleted.

Comment: CSS has lots of tricks and things to study and learn.
Maybe in your case it's not the answer

Comment: It's not my case that's relevant here, it's the question's case. Answers should _answer the question that was asked_. This answer does not do that, it discusses some totally different property, and opaquely refers to a different, unexplained problem that _you_ were facing at some point. If you want to provide a solution to that problem, I encourage you to do so, _as an answer to a question asking about that problem_, not on "the closest question you could find that is still about something else".