# Any idea how to use webkit fill available working on firefox and ie?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, webkit

I use css:

```
width: -webkit-fill-available;
height: -webkit-fill-available;
```

for my image, but in firefox and ie doesn't works.
i already used:

```
width: 100%
max-width: 100%;
```

but still now works.
this is example works on chrome but not in firefox and IE
[image: at firefox]

[image: at chrome]

Comment: faszinating, never heard of this property value, but here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275982/putting-moz-available-and-webkit-fill-available-in-one-width

Comment: ... where the answer is it works in FF but not IE or Edge.

Answer (score 3):

For Firefox you could use:

```
width: -moz-available;
```