# Dynamic Height of chat history with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using the Chat design from https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/message-chat-box inside a sidebar with `width:250px;` and a `margin-top:80px;` due to a bootstrap navbar.

However I want to resize the height of the chat history to fit the remaining height inside my page and I have no clue how to realize that. I tried `height:100%;` but that doesn't work.

you can find a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/yq3g9djc/

EDIT: I realized it now with jQuery. I calculate the window height and set the height of the chat history minus the offset.

Comment: please show minimal code

Comment: I added a jsfiddle at [http://jsfiddle.net/yq3g9djc/](http://jsfiddle.net/yq3g9djc/)

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain the code.

Answer (score 0):

Experimental css such as `height: -webkit-fill-available;` is one way. It's the laziest way to do it. The better way would be to style your page so that the chat panel can be placed on the right of it. Otherwise, doing anything fancy with this chat panel would prove difficult later on if you do not fix the issue properly now.

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275982/putting-moz-available-and-webkit-fill-available-in-one-width with your hint of using `-webkit-fill-available`. But this will make the input disappear in the bottom. how can I prevent this too?

Comment: Man, I wish I could be of some use, but the jsfiddle you've provided has an OK looking chat box. It fits just right. Though I advice that you use css to make sure that that box stays on the right. If you want an example of this, I can code something up for you.

Comment: My point is that the chat history currently have a fixed height in pixel. But to make it more responsive, I need a dynamic height plus the input box at the bottom.