# How to set width to fill-available in CSS for Microsoft Edge?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, doctype

I was making a page for Google Chrome and using `width: -webkit-fill-available` but when I tested for Microsoft Edge I noticed the width was different.

So I searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26276254) to support most browsers. Microsoft Edge ignores every width except `100%`.

After testing I noticed that it looks fine when I remove the [doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype) (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) but if I have it, which I believe is recommended, it doesn't look how it's suppost to.

Here's some simplified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div {
      background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    input,
    select {
      background: none;
      border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
      padding: 2%;
      width: 100%;
      /* Microsoft Edge */
      width: -moz-available;
      width: -webkit-fill-available;
      /* Google Chrome */
      width: fill-available;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <select></select><input>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

Microsoft Edge with doctype:

[image: Microsoft Edge with doctype]

Microsoft Edge without doctype:

[image: Microsoft Edge without doctype]

How can I set a width to fill the available space for both browsers and still maintain the doctype declaration? I want a generic solution that works the same way as `-webkit-fill-available`, not a specific one like `calc(100% - 4% - 2px)`.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%` should work in all browsers. No need for the prefixed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this just wrap your elements in a flex container:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}

select,
input {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input placeholder="stuff" />
</div>
```