How do I make the pre tag decrease in width?
How do I make the pre tag decrease in width? The pre tag prevents the q-card from decreasing, when the browser window is shrinking. I want a q-card that will contain a code similar to that in ChatGPT. However, the q-card does not decrease with the pre and code tags

Reproduction URL
https://codepen.io/timamus/pen/eYaNPQz
Code
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-ma-md">
    <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
      <q-page-container>
        <q-page class="flex flex-center">
          <q-list>
            <q-item class="justify-center">
              <q-item-section class="left-sec">
              </q-item-section>
              <q-item-section class="custom-message">
                <q-card flat bordered class="card-code">
                  <q-card-section style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
                    <pre>
                    <code>
                    {{ newMessage }}
                    </code>
                    </pre> 
                   <!-- <q-item-label> {{ newMessage }} <q-item-label> -->
                  </q-card-section>
                </q-card>
              </q-item-section>
              <q-item-section class="right-sec">
              </q-item-section>
            <q-item>
          </q-list>
        </q-page>
        <q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
  </div>

  <div class="q-ma-md">
    Running Quasar v{{ $q.version }}
  </div>
</div>


I would suggest to don't use a pre tag if you don't want to preserve the formatting. Just delete the opening and closing pre tags and the content inside the code tag will break to fit the width.

If you look here https://quasar.dev/vue-components/card and here https://chatgpt.com / then they also use the pre and code tags there

Ok, I think, I understood the question wrong at first. So you don't want the lines to break, only the pre tag to reduce the width? You could copy the structure of the HTML of the websites, you refer to and adjust it to your needs.

Use .q-list class by adding the width: -webkit-fill-available; to achieve the result.

I think it's not good because it doesn't work for Mozilla Firefox

@Timur You can add multiple browser vendor prefixes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26276254/5781499

Ok. Why exactly does qlist need this property? It doesn't work in a real similar component in my project

"You can try" is not an answer. Did you try this yourself? How would this answer the question

I'm just trying to figure out how it works in general. This works for the example in codepen. But it doesn't work in a real project. I also think it's better to avoid using such browser-specific properties.
